# Keep div's aspect ratio and fill it to window with CSS only

Tags: css

I need to make div fit to browser keeping 4:3 aspect ratio.

[image: screenshot]
How to make this with CSS only? All the solutions I've seen here won't help to make div fit.

Comment: you might wanna check this link https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For portrait screens, use a width of 100vw (the width of the window) and a height of 75vw (75% of the width of the window). For landscape screens, base the shape of the div on the height rather than the width.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
div {
  width: 100vw; height:75vw;
  background:#BBB;
  margin:0 auto;
}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
  div {
    width:133.33vh; height:100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check here if it answers your question
[Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

You can always go for javascript as well. Hope the link will help you